# Full Join in Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql

I am trying to use FULL JOIN on particular columns of two tables using HQL

```
List<B> expiredMacs = getHibernateTemplate()
                .find("from B b join A a where b.type != 'USER' and (b.id != a.id or (b.name == a.name and b.value != a.value))");
```

But it's throwing error unexpected token: = near line 1, column 325

Any idea what's going wrong?

in SQL

```
SELECT B.* FROM  B b, A a WHERE b.type != 'USER' AND (b.id != a.id or (b.name == a.name and b.value != a.value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution

```
List<B> expiredMacs = getHibernateTemplate()
            .find(SELECT b from B b, A a where b.type <> 'USER' and (b.id <> a.id or (b.name == a.name and b.value <> a.value)));
```

Comment: I would be interested in knowing how did you reach this result and what was your mistake before.

Comment: I was trying to slim down the SQL to HQL and by trail and error method I am able to make it successful and then understood why previous thing was failing

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `==` is not allowed, you should use `=`. See the [HQL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3188).

`!=` is allowed but it is preferable to use `<>` since it's closer to standard SQL.

Comment: Path expected for join!
Invalid path: 'b.name'
right-hand operand of a binary operator was nul

Comment: OK, I'll dig into that. Can you please provide us with the source code of A and B classes?

Comment: Sorry I can't They are much different. I indeed shared as example